# Prove every point between $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ is accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis

$x_n$ is bounded, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=0$, $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}=l$, $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}=L$, show that every point in $[l,L]$ is an accumulation point.

I am trying to use Stolz Cesàro theorem to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$, is it the right direction?

Comment: If you do show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$, what use would you have of this to answer your question? I think if you just use the definitions of $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$, and use that $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$ then you could come up with a direct and I would say straightforward proof.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $l<x<L$ but $x$ is not an accumulation point of $(x_n)$. Then there are $a,b$ such that $l<a<x<b<L$ and $(a,b)\setminus \{x\}\cap (x_n)=\emptyset.$ Now, there is an integer $N$ so large that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\frac{b-a}{2}$ whenever $n>N.$ But there is also an integer $M>N$ such that $x_M>b$ (why?). But then, if  $x_n\in \{x_M, x_{M+1},\cdots \},\ x_n>b$, from which it follows that $\liminf x_n\neq l$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by $(a,b)\cap (x_n)=\emptyset$?. It could well be the case that $x=x_0$, or that $x=x_m$ for *some* $m$, yet $x$ is not an accumulation point of the sequence of points $x_n$.

Comment: Yes, correct. The proof goes through unchanged though.

Comment: First you did change the proof, so it does not go unchanged. Second, I do not see what you mean by $(a,b)\setminus \{x\}\cap (x_n)=\emptyset$. It could be that case that $x_0$ , or $x_m$ for *some* other $m$ could be in  $(a,b)\setminus \{x\}$, yet $x$ is not an accumulation point of the sequence $x_n$.

Comment: if every neighborhood of $x$ contained a point from $(x_n)$ then $x$ would be an accumulation point, right? So there must exist an interval containing $x$ for which the intersection with $(x_n)$ is either null or consists of the singleton $\{x\}$ itself-

Comment: And the fact that one uses the punctured interval instead of the interval does not affect the proof: hence it goes through unchanged.

Comment: We may be thinking of different definitions of an accumulation point. One definition is accumulation point of a set, another is accumulation point of a sequence. The sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n=n\mod3$ has three accumulation points: $0,1$ and $2$ (with $1$ being a midpoint of $0$ and $2$) whereas the corresponding *set* $\{0,1,2\}$ has no accumulation points at all. I believe your answer is based on the *set* definition of an accumulation point. Both definitions are discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point. My first comment above stands (but the second only partially, I apologize)

Comment: I understand. That clears it up. Thanks.  I am using this definition (from Wiki): every neighbourhood of x with respect to the topology on X also contains a point of S other than x itself.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $p\in[l,L]$. If $p=l$ or $p=L$ we are done, so assume $l<p<L$. We want to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ and each positive integer $N$ there is $n_{\varepsilon,N}>N$ such that $|p-x_{n_{\varepsilon,N}}|<\varepsilon$.

Take $m$ such that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>m$. Take $k>\max\{m,N\}$ such that 
$|x_k-L|<L-p$, so in particular $p<x_k$. Take $j>k$ such that 
$|x_j-l|<p-l$, so in particular $x_j<p$. Consider the finite sequence of points 
$x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_{j-1},x_j$. There is an index $b$ with $k\le b\le j-1$ such that 
$x_b\ge p>x_{b+1}$. Using that $|x_{b+1}-x_b|<\varepsilon$ we have that 
$|x_b-p|<\varepsilon$ (and also $|x_{b+1}-p|<\varepsilon$). So we could take 
$n_{\varepsilon,N}=b$ (or also we could take $n_{\varepsilon,N}=b+1$), which completes the proof.

Regarding $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$ it holds regardless of the condition $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$, as long as the given sequence is bounded, in particular if $\lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty}=l$ and $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}=L$ exist and are finite numbers. But this condition $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$ does not necessarily imply that every $p\in(l,L)$ is an accumulation point. For example, take $x_n=0$ if $n$ is even, and take $x_n=1$ if $n$ is odd. Then $l=0$, $L=1$ and $l$ and $L$ are the only accumulation points, so no point $p\in(0,1)$ is an accumulation point. Thus Stolz Cesàro theorem that you refer to seems of no use for this problem. (As a matter of fact, after I reviewed the statement of Stolz Cesàro theorem, I do not quite see how it relates to the condition $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$, to begin with.)